# Swift 4 Decodable - No value associated with key CodingKeys

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I'm decoding a JSON response in my Swift App, and the code used to work till it decided to stop working.

this is my json reposnse

```
{
    "foods": [
        {
            "food_name": "Milk Chocolate",
            "brand_name": "Snickers",
            "serving_weight_grams": 41.7,
            "nf_calories": 212.3,
            "nf_total_fat": 11.6,
            "nf_saturated_fat": 4,
            "nf_total_carbohydrate": 22.7,
            "nf_protein": 3.9
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the code to decode my json

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        do {
            //Decode dataResponse received from a network request
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let foods = try decoder.decode(JSONFoods.self, from: data) //Decode JSON Response Data
            
            self.jsonfood = foods.JSONFood[0]
            print(self.jsonfood!)
            
        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }
        
    }
    task.resume()
```

And my Structs are

```
struct JSONFoods: Decodable {
var JSONFood: [JSONFood]    
}

struct JSONFood: Decodable{
var food_name: String
var brand_name: String
var nf_calories: Int
var nf_protein: Int
var nf_total_fat: Int
var nf_total_carbohydrate: Int
var serving_weight_grams: Int
}
```

And the error message I get is this

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "JSONFood", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "JSONFood", intValue: nil) ("JSONFood").", underlyingError: nil))

And if i get replace decode(**JSONFoods**.self, from: data) with decode(**JSONFood**.self, from: data)
I get this error message

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "food_name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "food_name", intValue: nil) ("food_name").", underlyingError: nil))

I searched everywhere with no luck, any help is very appreciated

Comment: `JSONFood` != `foods`.

Comment: For me, it is because some fields type in data model is not set to optional, which could be nil. When I set those fields to optional type, the error is gone. However, our API doc is poor, it doesn't mention which field could be nil.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let foods: [Food]
}

struct Food: Codable {
    let foodName: String?
    let  brandName: String
    let servingWeightGrams, nfCalories, nfTotalFat: Double
    let nfSaturatedFat: Int
    let nfTotalCarbohydrate, nfProtein: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case foodName = "food_name"
        case brandName = "brand_name"
        case servingWeightGrams = "serving_weight_grams"
        case nfCalories = "nf_calories"
        case nfTotalFat = "nf_total_fat"
        case nfSaturatedFat = "nf_saturated_fat"
        case nfTotalCarbohydrate = "nf_total_carbohydrate"
        case nfProtein = "nf_protein"
    }
}
```

**First :** you make `JSONFood` while it should be `foods`

**Second :**`food_name`  doesn't exist in current json  root so this will fail

```
let foods = try decoder.decode(JSONFoods.self, from: data) //Decode JSON Response Data
```

---

In case to take advantage of `convertFromSnakeCase`

```
let str = """

{"foods":[{"food_name":"Milk Chocolate","brand_name":"Snickers","serving_weight_grams":41.7,"nf_calories":212.3,"nf_total_fat":11.6,"nf_saturated_fat":4,"nf_total_carbohydrate":22.7,"nf_protein":3.9}]}

"""

    do {
        let res = JSONDecoder()
        res.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let ss = try res.decode(Root.self, from:Data(str.utf8))
        print(ss)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let foods: [Food]
}

struct Food: Codable {
    let foodName: String?
    let  brandName: String
    let servingWeightGrams, nfCalories, nfTotalFat: Double
    let nfSaturatedFat: Int
    let nfTotalCarbohydrate, nfProtein: Double
}
```

Comment: There is no need to rename the `JSONFoods` struct to `Root`.

Comment: i do it in case there are multiple structs for highlighting base model

Comment: The second error in the question occurs because the OP decodes the child struct `JSONFood` as root object. It has nothing to do that `food_name` could be missing. And why don't you suggest `.convertFromSnakeCase` strategy to get rid of the `CodingKeys`?

Comment: i just edit that before the comment :) , and yes i agree snake case is better but dynamic site generation may not take it  inconsideration for now =D