# I got this error in swift storyboard keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "topic", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError

Tags: json, swift

Error:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "topic", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "topic", intValue: nil) ("topic").", underlyingError: nil))

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var prizeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        

           // 1
           let urlString = "http:..{local-host-address}.../post"
           guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
           
           // 2
           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
               if error != nil {
                   print(error!)
               }

               guard let data = data else { return }
               do {
                   // 3
                   //Decode data
                   let JSONData = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSONTest.self, from: data)

                   // 4
                   //Get back to the main queue
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      
                       self.timeLabel.text = JSONData.time
                       self.priceLabel.text = JSONData.price
                       self.prizeLabel.text = JSONData.prize
                       self.contentLabel.text = JSONData.content
                       self.categoryLabel.text = JSONData.category
                       self.titleLabel.text = JSONData.topic
                       
                   }

               } catch let jsonError {
                   print(jsonError)
               }
               // 5
               }.resume()
       }
        
    }


    struct JSONTest: Codable {
        var topic: String
        var content: String
        var category: String
        var time: String
        var price: String
        var prize: String
        
        init(topic: String, content: String, category: String, time: String, price: String, prize: String) {
               self.topic = topic
               self.content = content
               self.category = category
               self.time = time
               self.price = price
               self.prize = prize
           }
    }
```

**BTW:** *I also have another similar code with different error but first I would like to solve this one*

***Thanks!***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 4 Decodable - No value associated with key CodingKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55562253/swift-4-decodable-no-value-associated-with-key-codingkeys)

Comment: This tells you server not share topic with you, please add optional to topic, and check if your problem has fixed like this: var topic: String? and share your result

Comment: if your problem no solved, you should edit your question and share your server json

Comment: Without knowing the json, it’s very hard to tell. Add `if let s = String(data: data) { print(s) }` to print the json returned and add the output to the question

Comment: @RezaKhonsari can you please demonstrate with a code

Comment: ```
{"scrims":[{"topic":"tv","content":"done","catagory":"gg","price":"Rs.100","prize":"Rs.1000","id":495818}]}
```
**THE JSON DATA** @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Add that to the question for clarity but you must always decode from the top level so add a struct with property scrims that is an array of JSONTest and use this new struct in your decode call

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it says "Value of type 'scrims' has no member 'time'"

Comment: this thing got me stuck for 2 days now.. imma cry soon

Comment: Then you didn't do what I said. `struct Root: Codable { let scrims: [JSONTest] }`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I did the exact same

Comment: There is no key "time" in your json so you can't add an extra property like that. If you want to have extra properties in your struct then you need to add a `CodingKeys` enum that list which properties the decoder should decode.

Comment: oke, ill try that.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson bro, still things are the same.. :(

Comment: ```
struct JSONTest: Codable {

        let topic: String
        let content: String
        let catagory: String
        let time: String
        let price: String
        let prize: String
        
        

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case topic = "topic"
                case content = "content"
                case catagory = "catagory"
                case time = "time"
                case price = "price"
                case prize = "prize"
        }
```

isn't it correct?

Comment: No, you can only include keys in the enum that exists in your json as I wrote. So remove `time` from the CodingKeys enum

Comment: nah bro... you got insta or anything? imma send some pics bro... this thing killing my brain..

Comment: @JoakimDanielson dude!!! it's telling the same for other things too

Comment: You need to troubleshoot this yourself, I can’t babysit you through all of this. If you don’t learn anything from the help you get then what is the point

Comment: yeah.. but, just shifted to iOS dev so I've got a lil less idea abt what's going on. I really need some good help on this rn..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS QUESTION WAS FIXED AFTER I DID SOME CHANGES:

FINAL CODE:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let url = URL(string: "http://{local-host}/post") {
           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
            let parsedJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode(parsingss.self, from: data)
                
                print(parsedJSON)
                    }
            catch {
            print(error)
                        
                    }
                   }
               }.resume()
            }
    }
    struct everything: Codable{
        let topic: String
        let content: String
        let category: String
        let time: String
        let price: String
        let prize: String
    }
    struct parsingss : Codable {
        let scrims: [everything]
    }
}
```

The data will be shown in the terminal.

I have no idea how to display it on a label btw..

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).